# Can you use iCloud locked iPhone like an iPod touch

Tags: iphone, icloud, ipod-touch

i already have an android smartphone and an old iPod touch. I want to upgrade my iPod touch. I was wondering if I can purchase an iCloud locked iphone cheaply and use it as an iPod touch - ie all the features except the phone, as I don't want it for the phone. Or are the features disabled when it is iCloud locked?

Comment: I don't believe you can buy a locked iPhone. Not from a proper store anyway (are there seriously stores that sell this kind of stuff?). In any case, IIRC, the entire phone is locked to protect the original user's data.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about. Carrier Locked phone.

Answer (score 2):

If you purchase a phone which is activation-locked via iCloud, you will not be able to use any features on it at all. This is different than a "locked" phone by carrier, which means that it can only be used on a certain carrier (such as AT&T). If that's the case, then the phone will work as a more robust iPod touch.